# Mixing isopropyl alcohol and propylene glycol

Tags: reaction-mechanism, everyday-chemistry

What would happen if I mixed isopropyl alcohol and propylene glycol? I need to winterize the water base of my basketball hoop, and already added some isopropyl alcohol, but I discovered that propylene glycol would be better.

Also, I know isopropyl alcohol is toxic to ingest, but will it contaminate my soil if I drain it?

Comment: If you'll mix them, you'll get a mixture of the two, and nothing more (no reactions or something). Both are toxic to ingest, and so will be the mixture. As for the contaminated soil, it will become toxic to ingest as well.

Comment: About how much isopropyl alcohol did you add to the water?

Comment: I want to point out that two of the close votes (one being mine) went towards ‘too broad’ because the question is asking two unrelated questions.

Answer (score 2):

The two chemicals can be mixed without any reaction between them. However, you should add enough water to avoid fire hazards after the winter. Take a look at [this table](http://www.advantageengineering.com/fyi/114/advantageFYI114.php) to find out, what mixture should suffice.

You should never pour solvents onto your soil or down the drain. Contact local authorities to find out, how you can safely dispose of that mixture. You can, of course, reuse the mixture and store it in some plastic cans if you need to empty the basketball hoop.

Comment: I accidentally switched the numbers. I revised my answer to give more options.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The table is for ethylene glycol, and I would like to use the less toxic propylene glycol. Is the table still valid?

Comment: I changed the link in my answer to [propylene glycol](http://www.advantageengineering.com/fyi/114/advantageFYI114.php). Now you should be good to go! :)